# Create AR Marker from image

Tags: c, augmented-reality, marker, artoolkit

In these days I'm working with ARToolKit and I'm faced the necessity to create AR Marker from a static image. So, as suggested in an old ARToolKit's newsletter, I'm started to writing my own video functions which should replace the standard Win32DirectShow function when I execute mk_patt.exe. My video function has the follow structure:

```
int arVideoOpen( char *config ) {
    return 0;
}

int  arVideoClose( void ){
    return 0;
}

int arVideoDispOption( void ){
    return 0;
}    

int arVideoInqSize( int *x, int *y ){
    *x = xsize; 
    *y = ysize; 
}

ARUint8 *arVideoGetImage( void )
{
    FILE *pFile;
unsigned long Size;
unsigned char *buffer;
size_t result;

    pFile = fopen("hhgf.bmp","rb");
    if(pFile==0){
        printf("Error!\n");
    }
    else{
        fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        Size = ftell( pFile );
        printf("Size: %d \n",Size);
        fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc (Size);
        if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
            result = fread (buffer, Size,1, pFile);
        if (result != Size) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); }
        return (ARUint8 *) buffer;
    }
}

int arVideoCapStart( void ){
    return 0;
}

int arVideoCapStop( void ) {
    return 0;
}

int arVideoCapNext( void )
{
    return 0;
}
```

The focal method is **arVideoGetImage** and it is supposed to return the data of my image. I'm not very expert with C so I put in the method some simple codes which I found on the web, but when I run mk_patt.exe, it crashes.
I need some help with how to code this or if this is the right way to reach my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved like this

```
ARUint8 *getBack(){
    int i;  
    unsigned char *buffer;
    int Size;
    FILE *streamIn;
    int byte;
    int count = 0;
    //printf("What wath %d \n",AR_DEFAULT_PIXEL_FORMAT);
    if(!isDef){
        image = (int *) malloc(400*400*sizeof(int));
         streamIn = fopen("hhgf.bmp", "rb");

            fseek( streamIn, 0, SEEK_END);
            Size = ftell(  streamIn );
            fseek( streamIn, 0, SEEK_SET);

         if (streamIn == (FILE *)0){
           printf("File opening error ocurred. Exiting program.\n");
           exit(0);
         }


        for(i=0;i<(Size-(400*400));i++) byte= getc(streamIn);
        i=0;
        while((count=getc(streamIn))!=-1){
            image[i]=count;
            i++;
        }

        fclose(streamIn);

        isDef=true;
    }

    return (ARUint8 *)image;
}


ARUint8   *arVideoGetImage( void ){
            return getBack();
 }
```